# How can I plot just the data with no borders using pylab

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib

Using pylab, I want to plot just the data with no axes or borders to a png file.  In code below, I still get borders to the left and right of the data.

```
import pylab
scores = [[ 82.,78.,    71.5,   76.,    79.5,   77.,    73.5,   70.5,   74.,    74.5 ],
[ 79. ,  75.75, 71.,   76.,   78.25, 73.25, 72.25 ,73.25, 74.75, 73.5 ],
[ 77.,   75.,   70.5,  73. ,  77.,   73.5,  71.75, 75.25, 76.75, 74.  ],
[ 76.,   74.75, 72.5,  72.25 ,75.25, 76.5,  73.5,  73.,   75.25, 75.75],
[ 75.,   72.5,  72.25, 74.5,  73.25, 73.25, 74.5,  73.25, 73.5,  76.5 ],
[ 74.5,  72.,   69.5,  73.25,  73.75,  72.,    76.75,  77.,    74.25,  76.5 ],
[ 72.5,   73.75,  72.75,  75.75,  78.,    76.75,  77.75,  78.75,  77.25,  74.  ],
[ 74.5,   74.25,  74.75,  78.75,  80.75,  79.25,  74.5,   75.,    76.25,  73.  ],
[ 75.5,   71.5,   71.75,  78.75,  80.25,  77.5,   75.,    73.25,  72.25,  72.75],
[ 77.5,   74.5,   72.,    77.75,  78.25,  74.,    76.75,  75.75,  74.25,  73.  ]]

fig = pylab.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels([None])
ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels([None])
ax.xaxis.set_ticks([None])
ax.yaxis.set_ticks([None])
ax.imshow(scores,vmin=0, vmax=100, origin='lower')
pylab.savefig('output.png',bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
```

Comment: I figured it out.  Two things needed doing.  First, tick labels and tick lines needed to be removed and when rendering the figure, set the bounding box to zero.  I'll edit my code snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pylab
scores = [[ 82.,78.,    71.5,   76.,    79.5,   77.,    73.5,   70.5,   74.,    74.5 ],
[ 79. ,  75.75, 71.,   76.,   78.25, 73.25, 72.25 ,73.25, 74.75, 73.5 ],
[ 77.,   75.,   70.5,  73. ,  77.,   73.5,  71.75, 75.25, 76.75, 74.  ],
[ 76.,   74.75, 72.5,  72.25 ,75.25, 76.5,  73.5,  73.,   75.25, 75.75],
[ 75.,   72.5,  72.25, 74.5,  73.25, 73.25, 74.5,  73.25, 73.5,  76.5 ],
[ 74.5,  72.,   69.5,  73.25,  73.75,  72.,    76.75,  77.,    74.25,  76.5 ],
[ 72.5,   73.75,  72.75,  75.75,  78.,    76.75,  77.75,  78.75,  77.25,  74.  ],
[ 74.5,   74.25,  74.75,  78.75,  80.75,  79.25,  74.5,   75.,    76.25,  73.  ],
[ 75.5,   71.5,   71.75,  78.75,  80.25,  77.5,   75.,    73.25,  72.25,  72.75],
[ 77.5,   74.5,   72.,    77.75,  78.25,  74.,    76.75,  75.75,  74.25,  73.  ]]

fig = pylab.figure(frameon=False)
ax_size = [0,0,1,1]
fig.add_axes(ax_size)
pylab.imshow(scores,vmin=0, vmax=100, origin='lower')
pylab.axis('off')
## As you noted.
pylab.savefig('output.png',bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
```

This should do it.  Doesnt show any axises for me.  All I did was add *frameon=False*.

Comment: That just makes the border transparent; the image still contains borders.

Comment: I found this: pylab.savefig('output.png',bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0) gets rid of most of the border, just leaves a three pixel edge on the left and bottom.

Comment: Yes, bbox_inches='tight' this should definitely get rid of the extra area.  Good job.